# Laravel - js sections of different blade files making conflict

Tags: php, laravel

I have two blade file and both of them has js section. But in the browser, shows only comments js files not single. I need to use both js files.

Here are blade files in a nutshell

**comments.blade**

```
// php and html codes
@section("js")
 // js codes of comments blade
@endsection
```

**single.blade**

```
@extends("master")
@section("content")
 // html and php codes 
 @include("comments")
@endsection
@section("js")
 // js codes of single blade
@endsection
```

Why there are conflict between two blade file ? And how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@append`:

**comments.blade**

```
// php and html codes
@section("js")
    // js codes of comments blade
@append
```

**single.blade**

```
@extends("master")

@section("content")
    // html and php codes 
    @include("comments")
@endsection

@section("js")
   // js codes of single blade
@append
```

I would recommend to use `@stack` though:

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks):

> Blade allows you to push to named stacks which can be rendered
>   somewhere else in another view or layout. This can be particularly
>   useful for specifying any JavaScript libraries required by your child
>   views:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

> You may push to a stack as many times as needed. To render the
>   complete stack contents, pass the name of the stack to the @stack
>   directive:

```
<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->

    @stack('scripts')
</head>
```